QueryParam being parsed as part of PathParam
When I use both jakarta.ws.rs @PathParam and @QueryParam, both params are being parsed as part of first PathParam.
Request:
/user/id11302908?asOf=2024-05-21

In jersey method mapping described like this:
    @GET
    @Path("/user/{id}")
    public Response getUser(@PathParam("id") final String id, @QueryParam("asOf") final String asOf) {
    System.out.println("id: " + id);
    System.out.println("asOf: " + asOf);
    return null; }

Output:
 id: id11302908?asOf=2024-05-21
 asOf: null

i.e. everything is being parsed as first PathParam (id). Isn't it supposed to stop at the question mark and interpret stuff after it as a QueryParam? Thanks!

Try using .path("/user/id11302908").queryParam("asOf","2024-05-21"). as a workaround

When everything is put on path parameter, the "?" character is percent-encoded and treated as a part of the path.
